# jshint incorrectly shows - Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: javascript, eclipse, socket.io, jshint, nodeclipse

I am running Eclipse:

Enide 2015
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: Nodeclipse-20150706-0921

with the following code:

```
var socketIo = require('socket.io');
var sio = socketIo.listen(server);
sio.in('time').emit('data', ioData.getjson()); //jshint ignore:line
```

and getting the below error message.

```
Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token
```

The code is fine and it is running fine. I would love to get rid of the error marking. Please let me know if you have a solution for this. Nothing suggested on the this forum back in 2014 seems to work including the jshint ignore line.

Comment: I think its the **in** in sio.in. try `sio ['in']('time')...` to check

Comment: Yes, it's the in in sio. That's the problem, but the code is running, so the syntax is OK. How can I get rid of the jshint error? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is pure JShint issue, try latest JSHint from command line to see if the issue has gone. (This is assuming that you have checked your settings in .jshintrc)